# Как реализовать временную шкалу с прокруткой и зумом?

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку.
Есть задача: реализовать андроид приложение - временную шкалу  с отметками событий на ней. Шкала на много экранов.

Какой элемент использовать для реализации отображения, прокрутки и зума?
Использовать canvas или что другое?

Comment: слишком широкий вопрос, конретизируйте!

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам - может кому пригодится.

Сделал все с помощью канвы. Вывод шкалы и событий в относительных координатах, которые меняются из события нажатия и претаскивания по экрану.
Для уменьшения нагрузки вывожу на экран только то, что вписывается размеры экрана.
Вот, собственно, алгоритм решения.